# All Attachments Need to be Downloaded

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, document

I am trying to keep users from being able to edit, and override, list attachments.  I would like to make it so they can only download the attachments no matter what they are.  Is there a way to do this?

If not, is there a way to to disable the edit document prompt when opened and keep it read-only?

Comment: give every body read permissions, so that no one can edit the item.

Comment: Does not matter for attachments.  They are still given the option to edit the item once opened in Word.  When they save it, it saves to the attachment.  I need to prevent that.  I do not want to use a document library either.

Comment: with read permission, they were able to update the attachemnt?

Comment: Yes.  I made a custom permission level to which they could only just look at the list item.  When the attachment is opened, they can edit it and save the edit back to the attachment.  I know in a Document library it will stay read-only, but I am using a custom list and would like them not to be able to open it at all.  Just download.